# Js перемещение картинок в форме

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем Здравствуйте!Есть форма с картинками:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу сделать перетаскивание этих картинок, то есть: Я зажимаю мышку и переношу картинку например на место второй, и вторая встает заместо первой, а первая сдвигается влево. Подскажите хотя бы в какую строну смотреть?Или как такое вообще можно реализовать

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Если будете писать все самостоятельно, напишите себе сначала алгоритм, что за чем будет идти и как между собой взаимодействовать. Вы так быстрее поймете что надо делать и в каком порядке. Ну а если вариант, прилепить что-то готовое, то просто подключите jQuery + все необходимое и вперед с песней (но понимания это не добавит, к сожалению). Это я вам из личного опыта говорю. Сейчас делаю так, раньше иначе (результат - дольше выполнял задания). Само действие это Drag’n’Drop.

Comment: @VladSpirin Мне кажется там дело не сколько в алгоритме, сколько в самом действии перетаскивания картинки. По логике Элементы дом после такой тасовки должны сами встать как и нужно

Comment: Вот тут вам и нужен алгоритм. По логике может быть, а если все пойдет не так........????? Продумайте весь механизм этого процесса и у вас будет все работать как швейцарские часы. Как вы будете делать, это конечно ваше дело, я лишь делюсь опытом попадания в мои лужи, вы их можете обойти...., или встать в свои, вам решать. [Посмотрите вот тут.](https://learn.javascript.ru/search?query=drag%27n%27drop) Думаю, вам это поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Привет. Если у тебя картинки достаются из БД, то можно сделать все очень красиво. У картинки будет дополнительное поле  типу "weight". На основании которого при выводе будет происходит сортировка. По дефолту поле равно 0.

Вот отличный пример с реализацией, код конечно можно сделать и покрасивей, но это то что тебе нужно.

Короче говоря, когда ты будешь выводить свои картинки, у каждого блока с картинкой должна быть ID с ID картинки в БД, для дальнейшего апдейта в условии WHERE. После того как ты их перетаскивал (drag n drop), на клиенте у тебя будет новая последовательность ID, JavaScript собирает эту последовательность и отправляет аяксом в контроллер, где происходит апдейт таблицы. ну по сути и все)

Тоже самое делал у себя под друпал. Идею брал отсюда, все класно работает.

Фишка в том что здесь можно сортировать grid, а не только таблицы.

[Демо](http://demos.codexworld.com/drag-drop-images-reorder-using-jquery-ajax-php-mysql/)
[Код](https://www.codexworld.com/drag-drop-images-reorder-using-jquery-ajax-php-mysql/)